# SQLAlchemy DateTime doesn't accept datetime.datetime.utcnow()

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a problem submiting post incto DB with a relationship. Here my sqlalchemy tables code. User and Post

```
class User(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
  password = db.Column(db.String(80))
  email = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
  avatar = db.Column(db.String(80))
  posts = relationship('Post', backref='owner', lazy='dynamic')

class Post(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  title = db.Column(db.String(128))
  body = db.Column(db.String(1024))
  date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
  author = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

I do:

```
from app import db, User, Post
```

Make a user and a post related to the user

```
user = User(username='username', password='password', email='mail@mail.com', avatar='image.jpg')
post = Post(title='title', body='body text', date=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), author=user)
```

And commit it

```
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
db.session.add(post)
db.session.commit()
```

Then I always get the same error:

```
(sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 3 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: 'INSERT INTO post (title, body, date, author) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)']
[parameters: ('title', 'body text', '2017-06-16 08:48:55.651632', <app.User object at 0x04C11770>)]
```

I have tried a lot of different solutions, but none of then worked.

Comment: whatv solutions did you try and why didnt they work?

Comment: The problem is not the datetime, but your `User` object that you're trying to pass to an integer column. You've mixed a plain foreign key column and an ORM relationship attribute. You have the former, but it would seem you wanted the latter. A quick fix is to `Post(..., author=user.id)`.